# Winsock отправка массива типа vector

Tags: c++, winsock

Имею такую матрицу `vector<vector<float>> matrix` n-го размера. каким образом ее передать через сокеты на сервер. Вектор используется, потому что создать обычный массив float n-го размера нельзя. Есть реализация сделанная мною, она передает каждый элемент по отдельности через send(), но данный процесс слишком долог. В интернете не нашел ничего толкового. Заранее благодарен всем кто откликнется

Comment: Вам нужно сериализировать вектор-векторов в массив. А собственно массив уже можно передать.

Comment: Не подскажите, при помощи чего можно это произвести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много способов. самый простой - передавать вектора - вектор это непрерывная структура, поэтому, можно передать размер вектора и потом весь вектор.

схематически.

```
// отправим размер вектора
vector<vector<float>> v;
send(v.size(), sizeof(v.size()));
// в цикле отправляем каждый кусочек, с размером и данными
for (auto& x : v) {
  send(x.size(), sizeof(x.size()));
  send(x.data(), x.size()*sizeof(float));
}
```

send - это функция отправки. Да, там типы нужно будет аккуратно привести, но это справитесь.

На приемной стороне читается размер, потом вычитываются вложенные данные.

где то так:

```
vector<vector<float>> data;
size_t t;
read(&t, sizeof(t));
data.resize(t);
for (size_t i = 0; i < t; i++) {
  size_t ti;
  read(&ti, sizeof(ti));
  data[i].resize(ti);
  read(data[i].data(), sizeof(float)*ti);
}
```

*предупреждение:*

- нет никакой проверки валидности.
- если плаформа/компилятор отличается, то могут быть проблемы.
- желательно добавить пару байт заголовка/концовки, что бы проверять, что данные прочитаны правильно.

Второй способ - сделать это все строкой, например, через запятую или что то вида json. А дальше все просто.

Третий способ - использовать protobuf или подобное.

Comment: Прошу прощения за тупость, но вот механизм получения из передачи, я не совсем как понимаю реализовать

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. При не больших размерах матрицы скажем 27*27 все работает. Но как только ее размер переваливает за 1300*1300. При передаче через 1 сокет на сервер 2-ух таких матриц одной за одной. Вторая не приходит. Какие тут  могут быть варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Для начала переписать коментарий так, что бы он был понятнее. А то второе предложение как то в стороне стоит.  Потом взять код, который воспроизводит проблему и создать новый вопрос

Comment: создал новую тему

Answer (score 0):

Я пошел почти по этому пути. Так как программа считает исключительно квадратную матрицу. И мы знаем изначально количество строк = количеству столбцов. То я решил в каждой отсылке не пересылать размер строки, а пересылать непосредственно строку.

Код отправки с клиента:

```
bool sendMatrix(SOCKET socket, int masLength, vector<vector<float>> matrix)
{
bool result = true;

for (auto& x : matrix)
{
    send(socket, (char*)x.data(), x.size() * sizeof(float), 0);
}
return result;
}
```

Код на стороне сервера:

```
vector<vector<float>> recvMatrix(SOCKET socket)
{
vector<vector<float>> matrix;
matrix.resize(masLength);
for (int i = 0; i < masLength; i++)
{
    matrix[i].resize(masLength);
    recv(socket, (char*)matrix[i].data(), sizeof(float)*masLength, 0);
}
return matrix;
}
```

Параметр masLength принимается на сервере первым. Это как раз и есть количество строк. На сервере при помощи этого параметра и создаем необходимые размеры для вектора.